# java.sql.SQLException: Field 'client_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying, using JSON (via Postman) to use POST and GET methods on my database tables (**Clients**, **Cars** and **Rentals**), where **clients_id** and **cars_id** are foreign keys in **Rentals** table.

I'm not sure if I done the foreign keys mapping right, because everything works just fine for Clients and Cars tables.

This is how I tried to do this in my **Rental** entitites class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="rentals")
public class Rentals {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private Date rental_date;
    private String status;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="client_id")
    private Clients client;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="car_id")
    private Cars car;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Clients getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Clients client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public Cars getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(Cars car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    public Date getRental_date() {
        return rental_date;
    }

    public void setRental_date(Date rental_date) {
        this.rental_date = rental_date;
    }
}
```

Also these are my entites class for **Clients**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="clients")
public class Clients {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer client_id;

    public Integer getClient_id() {
        return client_id;
    }

    public void setClient_id(Integer client_id) {
        this.client_id = client_id;
    }

    private String name,surname,place_of_residence,id_number;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getPlace_of_residence() {
        return place_of_residence;
    }

    public void setPlace_of_residence(String place_of_residence) {
        this.place_of_residence = place_of_residence;
    }

    public String getId_number() {
        return id_number;
    }

    public void setId_number(String id_number) {
        this.id_number = id_number;
    }
}
```

and **Cars**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cars")
public class Cars {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer car_id;

    private String brand,model,licence_plate_number,production_year,price_per_day;

    public Integer getCar_id() {
        return car_id;
    }

    public void setCar_id(Integer car_id) {
        this.car_id = car_id;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getLicence_plate_number() {
        return licence_plate_number;
    }

    public void setLicence_plate_number(String licence_plate_number) {
        this.licence_plate_number = licence_plate_number;
    }

    public String getProduction_year() {
        return production_year;
    }

    public void setProduction_year(String production_year) {
        this.production_year = production_year;
    }

    public String getPrice_per_day() {
        return price_per_day;
    }

    public void setPrice_per_day(String price_per_day) {
        this.price_per_day = price_per_day;
    }
}
```

This is the JSON enquiry that i'm using:

```
{
"client_id":2,
"car_id":4,
"rental_date":"2017-06-05",
"status":"rented"
}
```

Also, here's my **RentalsController** Class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rentals")
public class RentalsController {

    private final RentalsRepository rentalsRepository;

    public RentalsController(RentalsRepository rentalsRepository){
        this.rentalsRepository = rentalsRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addRental(@RequestBody Rentals rental){
        rentalsRepository.save(rental);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Rentals> getRentals(){
        return rentalsRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**Error**:

```
2017-06-14 11:02:57.893  WARN 3932 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2017-06-14 11:02:57.894 ERROR 3932 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'car_id' cannot be null
2017-06-14 11:02:57.898 ERROR 3932 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'car_id' cannot be null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2490) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2855) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3426) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:619) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:775) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:508) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at eu.fitk.controllers.RentalsController.addRental(RentalsController.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_73]
```

*Edit 1:* following advices from @Dazak and @Wolf, I changed the columns names that I wanted to join (aka foreign keys in **Rentals** table) to client_id and car_id.

Also, I tried to change the PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation to JoinColumn annotation, but none of these worked. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you in advance for your help!

*Edit 2:* I also changed names of primary keys in Clients and Cars tables in my database to client_id and car_id (not sure if it is a proper way to handle the problem), but still, it didn't help.

Comment: As I can see... in the Client entity there's no field `client_id` just `id`, also in your Json you have `date_of_rental` but in the Rental entity the field is `rental_date`

Comment: the JSON i pasted was outdated, i corrected that. I'll check the thing with client_id/id you mentioned.

Comment: shouldn't there be just @JoinColumn instead of @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn? Also what Dazak says, the client_id seems to have wrong name

Comment: ok i'm not sure if i undestrood you well, i changed the ID name in Client class to @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer client_id; and same for Cars class, but it still shows the same error as before.

Comment: changing annotation to @JoinColumn didn't help too

Comment: pasted the correct classes Clients and Cars

Comment: so guys, do you have any ideas what else can be wrong here? :d

Comment: Taking another look to the problem... in your entity `Clients` you do not have the getter and setter method to the `client_id` attribute, however, in your stackTrace it says _Column 'car_id' cannot be null_ and in your Json you do pass that attribute, so I will say that your problem must be in the mapping between your Json and Java or in the relation between Rentals and Cars

Comment: @Dazak there is getter and setter for client_id attribute in my enity Clients, and yes, i have no idea why it only points to the car_id

Comment: put a System.out in the addRental method in RentalsController class to to print all attributes of  the object Rental that is build with the json just to be sure that object is constructed as you expected

Comment: @Dazak sorry, but i don't know how to do it, i tried printing out rental.getCar() but it gave me "null" output.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work. If you are using an ORM model you can't work with IDs anymore. You request provides a client_id and a car_id:

```
{
"client_id":2,
"car_id":4,
"rental_date":"2017-06-05",
"status":"rented"
}
```

However, the Rentals object (!) does neither have a property called car nor client. I guess these additional properties are simply ignored. What the Rental object does have is a reference to car and client objects (!) that hold those IDs.

So you JSON has to look something like this:

```
{
 "client":{"client_id": 2}   
 "car":{"car_id": 4},
 "rental_date":"2017-06-05",
 "status":"rented"
}
```

(I hope my JSON is correct. I am not very familiar with JavaScript.)

BTW: You OneToOne mapping seems wrong. Unless you are renting out each car only once to one customer it should be a ManyToOne.